# Cannot load ubuntu (empty grub)

Tags: boot, grub2, nvme

I had a working version of Ubuntu 18.04 and upon trying to install displaylink drivers my entire system stopped loading.
It is on an NVME ssd drive.
Here is the boot repair log.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5gghDVJMSx/
I am at a loss.

Comment: Hey installed displaylink 5.1 drivers today myself and didn't get any issues with boot so I don't think those two are related. See updateFailure section in the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery doc

Comment: Yes I do not think it was automatic. I had done it before without issues, but this time I accidently included the dkfms commands